# How to call first array element in smarty

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, template-engine

I have associative array:

```
 Array ( [7] => Array ( [media_id] => 7 ) Array ( [8] => Array ( [media_id] =>      8 ) Array ( [5] => Array ( [media_id] => 5 ) Array ( [18] => Array ( [media_id] => 18 )
```

I need to call only the first element with smarty template engine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{$arrayVar|@array_shift}
```

Comment: I need to call first element without foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

You should reset the array once again.

```
$arrayNew=reset($arrayOld);
$value=$arrayNew[0];
```

value will return the first element.